# mvc mini profiler problem

Tags: c#, mvc-mini-profiler, code-first

I'm trying to get the mini profiler working with code first and am having a problem. I've got the miniprofiler and miniprofiler.ef packages from nuget and have added the

```
MiniProfilerEF.Initialize();
```

to the application start method but when I try and perform a query I get this error.

```
The given assembly name or codebase was invalid. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131047)
```

and thoughts on why this could be?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: yeah sorry should have put that in, its code first so...

Comment: ahh it would seem it might be a known issue http://code.google.com/p/mvc-mini-profiler/issues/detail?id=100#c4

Comment: did you nuke out the old changes to web.config ?

Comment: @Sam yeah, there is no reference to mini in web.config at all.

Comment: Let's hope this will be fixed by the EF team soon. EF query profiling was really, really helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a known problem with no solution at present. to keep upto date on it look here [code.google.com/p/mvc-mini-profiler/issues/detail?id=100#c4](http://code.google.com/p/mvc-mini-profiler/issues/detail?id=100#c4)

Answer (score 0):

If you use it as httpmodule then check names in web.config, probably there is a type there.